# Turing Machine substring

Tags: turing-machines, substrings

I want to create a turing machine that describes the language L={x#y | x,y\in {0,1}* and x is a substring of y}.
However I'm not sure how to start writing the transition function δ as I've just gotten acquainted with turing, can you point me the transitions so I can draw the state diagram and understand more?

Comment: Just an idea.
MDT M with input x#y :
go back and forth along the ribbon between the corresponding positions of the substrings separated by the # symbol, and check if these positions contain the same symbol. If not, or if no # symbol is found, REJECT; otherwise if the symbols match replace them with the X symbol (special symbol);
when all the symbols to the left of the # have been replaced with an X, check if there are others left not marked on the right. If yes, then REFUSE; otherwise ACCEPT.

Comment: I think it work but what would be the state diagram of it?